# how to list serial com ports (via usb or real) excluding bluetooth with java idealy or wmi?

Tags: java, powershell, windows-10, serial-port, windows-7-x64

i have to modify a program that is disturbed by BT ports and would like to filter avaible ports to list only rs232 or rs232 via usb to user.

I saw that jssc doesnt allow the getproperty method so i'm trying to do that using powershell cmd. this filter has to work on win10 and win7.

As first step i started tests using that but i don't how to filter results to see only pnpclass="ports"

``gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{wmi} |select name, pnpclass `

Thank you

Comment: What powershell version are you running? Save yourself the trouble and use, `Get-PnPDevice`.

Comment: powershell of win7 cannot run "Get-PnPDevice"   . psversion 2

Comment: but youre right the thing i would like to obtain is the equivalent of                                      Get-PnPDevice -class 'ports' -status 'ok'  for ps 2

Comment: Then you'll probably have better luck using `Get-WmiObject -Class win32_PNPEntity`. Should give you the status as well.

Comment: You may have luck with `Win32_PNPEntity` or `Win32_SerialPort` and the `GetRelated()` method, but both of those rely on the hardware vendor populating the data appropriately. In my experience, Serial to USB vendors don't spend a lot of time on, well, anything, but certainly not their drivers.

Comment: thanks to both of you. the question now is how to use filter or select option to just have a list for each port with comX , associated name and satus   like pnpdevice do ? i 'm trying to find examples of way to filter but hard to find

Comment: for example : (Get-WmiObject -Class win32_pnpentity | where {$_.name -like "*usb*"  }) its ok but i would like to  consolidate addind "*serial*" word search in name property how to add AND operator ?